# standardValueSets not being used in production org

Tags: salesforcedx

After creating a standardValueSet for standard object field `Product2.Family` picklist in a scratch org and successfully installing the package using `sfdx force:package:install...`, the picklist still only has the default value `None`

Why isn't the picklist picking up the new set of values that show correctly in the scratch org?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Unlocked Packages ?

If so, standardValueSets are not supported (yet?) in Unlocked Packages, so they are not deployed.

You can have a look to what's supported and what's not in Unlocked Packages in the [Metadata Coverage Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/45).

Comment: thank you! we've recently switched to using MDAPI